# Low performance on SET based query with COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following stored procedure, it assesses all the accounts in a staging table and decides if they are suitable to import or not. If they are it will flag them as suitableToImport = TRUE. If not will give a reason why not.

Although it's SET based its still very slow. I've tried moving to EXIST instead of COUNT, but testing do not seem to indicate it would make much of a difference.

Any recommendation on what could be done?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION assessInclusionOfAccountsFromStaging () RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$ /*Only new accounts are valid, detailed issues checking and budge checking duplicates*/

DECLARE
    countOfAccountsInStaging INTEGER;
BEGIN

    /*Check that we have data to process*/
    countOfAccountsInStaging = COUNT(*) FROM importAccountsStaging;
    IF(countOfAccountsInStaging) = 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No accounts available';
    END IF; 

    /*SET SuitableToImport*/
    RAISE NOTICE 'Processing accounts...';
    UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET suitableToImport = TRUE 
    WHERE 
        AND ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM importAccountsStaging as accountsIterated /*Check for duplicates against staging enviroment at org level*/
            WHERE 
                (accountsIterated.code1 = importAccountsStaging.code1)
                OR (accountsIterated.code2 = importAccountsStaging.code2)
            )=1)

        /*Check for duplicate in masterdb*/
        AND ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM masterAccounts /*Check for any potential duplicate at org level*/
            WHERE 
                (importAccountsStaging.code1 = masterAccounts.code1 )
                OR (importAccountsStaging.code2 = masterAccounts.code2 )
            )=0)
        ;

        /*SET COMMENT on why it's not suitable to import*/
        UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(reason , 'existing account in staging|')
        WHERE
            NOT ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM importAccountsStaging as tempAccounts 
            WHERE 
                tempAccounts.code1 = importAccountsStaging.code1
                OR tempAccounts.code2 = importAccountsStaging.code2 
            )=1);


            /*SET COMMENT on why it's not suitable to import*/
        UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(reason , 'existing account in main|')
        WHERE
        NOT ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM masterAccounts
        WHERE 
            importAccountsStaging.code1 = masterAccounts.code1
            OR importAccountsStaging.code2 = masterAccounts.code2
        )=0)
        ;

    /*Return values*/
RAISE NOTICE 'Assessment completed human! ';
RETURN  TRUE;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the optimized query, I took inputs from all of the answers so thanks a lot for your help. The changes made the query execute in about 7 minutes down from over 10 hours.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION assessInclusionOfAccountsFromStaging () RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$ /*Only new accounts are valid, detailed issues checking and budge checking duplicates*/

DECLARE
    countOfAccountsInStaging INTEGER;
BEGIN

    /*Check that we have data to process*/
    countOfAccountsInStaging = COUNT(*) FROM importAccountsStaging;
    IF(countOfAccountsInStaging) = 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No accounts available';
    END IF; 

    RAISE NOTICE 'Processing accounts...';
    /*Checking value of row against the table the row belongs to for potential duplicates*/
    UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(importAccountsStaging.reason , 'existing code1 in staging|')
    WHERE ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM importAccountsStaging as tempAccounts 
        WHERE 
            tempAccounts.code1 = importAccountsStaging.code1
        )>1);
    UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(importAccountsStaging.reason , 'existing code2 in staging|')
    WHERE ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM importAccountsStaging as tempAccounts 
        WHERE 
            tempAccounts.code2 = importAccountsStaging.code2
        )>1);

    /*Checking value of row against another table*/
    UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(importAccountsStaging.reason , 'existing code1 in masterDB|')
    FROM masterAccounts  WHERE importAccountsStaging.code1 = masterAccounts.code1;
    UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(importAccountsStaging.reason , 'existing code2 in masterDB|')
    FROM masterAccounts  WHERE importAccountsStaging.code2 = masterAccounts.code2;

    /*Final flag where no issues were found*/
    UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET suitableToImport = TRUE 
    WHERE reason IS NULL;

    /*Return values*/
RAISE NOTICE 'Assessment complete, all done! ';
RETURN  TRUE;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You might also want to try the following for the checks on staging:

UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET reason = CONCAT(importAccountsStaging.reason , 'existing code1 in staging|')
FROM (SELECT code1 FROM importAccountsStaging GROUP BY code1 HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS duplicates WHERE importAccountsStaging.code1 = duplicates.code1

I think my syntax is right!  This may be faster.
In any case 10 hours down to 7 minutes is an improvement to be proud of!  Please remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWillcock, will look into it. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is known antipattern - generally `COUNT(*)` can be pretty slow operation because it have to scan all possible rows. Test based on `EXISTS` should be pretty fast, because the execution stops on first row. So **newer use COUNT for test if some exists or not!** Use `EXISTS` always.

Comment: Highly unlikely that the `count(*)` is the real performance problem in the query.  See my answer.

Comment: the query with `exists` and `count` should to have different plans - sure, there can be be other issues - the `OR` operator doesn't help, but the main problem is using `count` in sense `exists`

Comment: This did help, but did not improve the performance enough. We were still in the over 6h time.

Comment: UPDATE is pretty expensive operation, MERGE two big tables too. New PostgreSQL 9.5 has form of UPSERT https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-insert.html `INSERT ON CONFLICT`. You can try another UPSERT implementation based on CTE https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/upsert-records-with-postgresql-9-5 - and you need lot of memory to hold active data in cache or fs cache.

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` in the correlation clause is a killer -- it is probably causing a full table scan for each record in the table being updated.

Assuming you are just looking for existence and not the actual count, I would suggest:

```
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM importAccountsStaging ias
               WHERE ias.code1 = importAccountsStaging.code1
              ) OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM importAccountsStaging ias
               WHERE ias.code2 = importAccountsStaging.code2
              )
      ) AND
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM masterAccounts ma
                   WHERE importAccountsStaging.code1 = ma.code1 
                  ) AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM masterAccounts ma
                   WHERE importAccountsStaging.code2 = ma.code2
                  ) 
      )
```

Then you want indexes on `importAccountsStaging(code1)`, `importAccountsStaging(code2)`, `masterAccounts(code1)`, and `masterAccounts(code2)`.

If you are looking for specific counts, you can modify the logic for that as well (and it should be almost as fast).

Comment: Thanks! Looking at it now, will report back.

Comment: Although this did improve performance, the main problem was that some of the checks had to verify a data point of one row against the table were the row was. This means the row would always EXIST at least once, I wanted to know if it existed twice or more. So I was forced to still use COUNT for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a complete re-design to get rid of the ORs altogether.  I strongly suspect that if you break the operation down into smaller chunks, it will run much faster.  For example rather than SELECT COUNT(*) on masterAccounts, why not do:

UPDATE importAccountsStaging 
SET reason = CONCAT(reason , 'existing account in main|')
FROM masterAccounts
WHERE importAccountsStaging.code1 = masterAccounts.code1;

UPDATE importAccountsStaging 
SET reason = CONCAT(reason , 'existing account in main|')
FROM masterAccounts
WHERE importAccountsStaging.code2 = masterAccounts.code2;

And similar for your other checks ... then simply at end

UPDATE importAccountsStaging SET suitableToImport = TRUE 
WHERE reason is null

Comment: This was very helpful, I used this for almost all checks, together with Index raised above and it calculates way faster.

Comment: Note that the combination I just mentioned above works great when the value to test for is an integer, not as well when its varchar. Way slower.

Comment: @MMV Thanks for the feedback. Glad it helped